# Proper Syntax for Oracle IMPDP REMAP_DIRECTORY

Tags: oracle, impdp

I'm installing Oracle XE 18c on a Windows 10 platform.  I'm following the instructions in https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinw/exporting-and-importing-data-oracle-database-xe-11.2-and-18c.html#GUID-6C55327E-2701-426B-A55A-3A576DC78FCE   I'm using the section 9.2 - Exporting and Importing Data for Oracle Application Express Users.
I exported the data from my original system, and it completed successfully.  I transferred the dump file (DB11G.dmp) to my new system in the folder C:\SS_BACKUPS.
On the original source system the files are located in: C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE
On the new target system (different hardware) the files will be located in: C:\app\product\18.0.0\oradata\XE
On the new target system I executed the following commands in SQLPLUS:

```
sqlplus SYS AS SYSDBA
SQL> CREATE DIRECTORY BACKUP_DIR AS 'C:\SS_BACKUPS';
SQL> GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY BACKUP_DIR TO SYSTEM;
SQL> GRANT IMP_FULL_DATABASE to SYSTEM;
```

Then from a privileged DOS prompt I ran the command:

```
impdp system/(my_password)@localhost/xepdb1 full=Y REMAP_DIRECTORY='C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\':'C:\app\product\18.0.0\oradata\XE\' directory=BACKUP_DIR dumpfile=DB11G.dmp logfile=impdpDB11G.log
```

When I execute that, I get the error: `UDI-00014: invalid value for parameter, 'remap_directory'`,

I understand the structure of the REMAP_DIRECTORY to be SOURCE:TARGET
Any idea why I'm receiving that error?
Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, you must have the DATAPUMP_IMP_FULL_DATABASE  role to use the REMAP_DIRECTORY option.

**Update 1**

According to documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-5DA84A72-B71C-4491-9DD8-7075D9A4B04F

> Depending on your operating system, escape characters can be required
>   if you use quotation marks when you specify a value for this
>   parameter. Oracle recommends that you place this parameter in a
>   parameter file, which can reduce the number of escape characters that
>   you otherwise would require on the command line.

So, it says try putting the REMAP_DIRECTORY option in a parameter file instead to remove any ambiguities about escaping paths etc.

I think in your case it might be that the colon in the paths perhaps needs escaping or hiding from the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Sadly, I tried it and got the same result.

Comment: What version of impdp are you using? Check with `impdp help=yes`.

Comment: And also try wrapping the value in double quotes, as per the Oracle documentation, e.g. `REMAP_DIRECTORY="'c:\the_dir\':'c:\the_new_dir\'"`.

Comment: Hi TenG.  The banner line of the help reads: Import Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sat Feb 23 07:50:08 2019 Version 18.4.0.0.0

Comment: I tried the double-quotes, like so: impdp system/(my_password)@localhost/xepdb1 full=Y REMAP_DIRECTORY="'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\':'C:\app\product\18.0.0\oradata\XE\'" directory=BACKUP_DIR dumpfile=DB11G.dmp logfile=impdpDB11G.log             Same result

Comment: See Update 1 to answer.

Comment: Hi TenG.  The parameter file worked.  I created a file called impdp_remap_directory.par.  The contents are:
userid=system(my_password)@localhost/xepdb1  
full=Y  
REMAP_DIRECTORY="'C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\oradata\XE\':'C:\app\product\18.0.0\oradata\XE\'"  
directory=BACKUP_DIR  
dumpfile=DB11G.dmp  
logfile=impdpDB11G.log
The IMPDP ran fine, but it resulted in 818 errors.  It seems that the procedure didn't create the schema first, resulting in a slew of errors.  I might just try to use IMPDP for the one schema I have and then install Apex 18.2 after that.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: My RUN statement for the above was: impdp parfile=impdp_remap_directory.par